# cURL PHP and problem with the SSL CA cert

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm not able to use CA cert with the PHP code below

```
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__.'/my-cert.cer' );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, __DIR__.'/my-cert.cer');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $curl_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);

print_r($decoded);
```

It always throws an error

> Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

I have looked at other similar questions but all of them were pointing to `/etc/pki/tls/certs` not specified cert only for that code.

**PS**

I have commented out

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, __DIR__.'/var/www/html/my-cert.cer');
```

and now getting that error:

> Error in TLS handshake, trying SSLv3...

**PS2.**

It must to have something with NSS as I have updated to nss-3.36.0-9.el6_10.x86_64 and got it to work but then part of the web application stopped to work as should.

Comment: The path looks fishy. Do you really want the `__DIR__` in front of `/var/www/...`?

Comment: Try to delete __DIR__. part (including period), as @WillardSolutions suggested you, from both lines.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto I have done and didn't helped. It came up that I need to update NSS but after updating that part of the web app is not working as should.

Comment: what part are not working? what error did you have?

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto it fails somehow on another cURL call at `$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);` but no error message there. Web app is expecting results from that call but didn't error out so is failing

Comment: Can you copy your complete curl call who is failing? Maybe there's something on it.Maybe the curl_options are shared and some of them are not valid for these call? Also try to set error reporting to ALL and check server logs, maybe curl_error is not giving you anything but there's a php error on some place.